# I have internal server error 500 when I tried to post json in Jquery ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, json, ajax

When I try to send json JSON.stringify(coords); or above code I get error message but I try when the data is empty like data:{} the code works correctly. How can I solve this problem?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {"yagiz":"aabb"},
    dataType: 'json',
    url: url,
    crossDomain:true,
    async: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (response) {
        $("#Content").text(response.d);
        console.log(response.d);
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
        console.log(response.d);
    }
});
```

**Web Method**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod] 
public static string GetLocationPolygon(string location)
{
     return location; 
}
```

Comment: A 500 error means that the error is on the server, not your JS. We cannot help you without seeing the server-side code, or at least the error from the network console.

Comment: You need to know how the web API (URL you're sending the request to) works in order to understand how it got an internal server error

Comment: [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string GetLocationPolygon(string location) {
            
            return location;
        }

Comment: This is my server side code.

Comment: Check the network console to see what the *exact* error is

Comment: data:JSON.stringify({"location":"aabb"})..... try this code

Comment: "Message":"Incorrect basic JSON element: yagiz.","StackTrace":"   konum: System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()\r\n

Comment: @SatishSam it is not working

Comment: did you serialize whatever you are returning from your web method??

Comment: please share your webmethod code

Comment: whatever I tried I have same problem [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string GetLocationPolygon(string location) {
            
            return location;
        }                       also this simple code gives same error @SatishSam

Comment: try,  data: JSON.stringify({location:"xyz"})

Comment: what's the location variable contained in the webmethod which you are returning

Comment: @ShekharPankaj Thank you, it solved this problem but i have to send an array like {{0,0},{0,0}} this array is a javascript variable how can I convert and post it?

Comment: @SatishSam it is a multi dimensional array

Comment: @ygzmglkc try using `LIST` as parameter create an array of object containing co-ordinates value and pass them to web-method

Answer (score 1):

You can debug on server side as 500 internal error raised at server side only. You can catch and log the exact exception.

Answer (score 0):

**try this code**

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({"location":"aabb"}), //Change here
        dataType: 'json',
        url: url,
        crossDomain:true,
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (response) {
            $("#Content").text(response.d);
            console.log(response.d);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
            console.log(response.d);
        }
    });
```